# SQL test empty string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this query.
I want to
get records in date range -> DONE
get records where PriorSurgery = 'Yes' -> DONE
get records where Consultant not blank - NOT WORKING

How do I test for no blank.
Ive tried `AND adm.adm_Consultant != ''`
Ive rried `AND adm.adm_Consultant <> ''`

And the one below (which looks the better way to do it)

Where am i going wrong?

```
SELECT adm.adm_Consultant, adm.adm_PriorSurgery
FROM Admission adm
WHERE  adm.adm_ReferralDate >= '01/01/2014 00:00:00' AND adm.adm_ReferralDate <= '31/12/2014 00:00:00'  
AND adm.adm_PriorSurgery = 'Yes',
AND LENGTH(adm.adm_Consultant) > 0
```

Comment: Maybe the Consultant field is not empty, but NULL? Try `AND adm.adm_Consultant IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: For Oracle dbms, where `''` is the same as a `NULL` string, comparison to `''` will never yield true.

Comment: Shouldn't the upper limit of the referraldate be '31/12/2014 23:59:59'? Just in case someone is referred on new years eve...

Comment: @KlasLindbäck, yes in all other cases probably. This however is measured in calendar days, so the Time has no effect. Thanks for the observation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are null then

```
SELECT adm.adm_Consultant, adm.adm_PriorSurgery
FROM Admission adm
WHERE  adm.adm_ReferralDate >= '01/01/2014 00:00:00' AND adm.adm_ReferralDate <= '31/12/2014 00:00:00'  
AND adm.adm_PriorSurgery = 'Yes'
AND adm.adm_Consultant IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. Works great yes. Just one other thing. Bit of a face palm effect. The comma after `AND adm.adm_PriorSurgery = 'Yes',` also caused a problem. `LENGTH` worked as-well after removing it. Thanks

Comment: i missed that one too! Yeah, i would use is not null though, as (depending on your data size) LENGTH > 0 would take longer to process